# How can i add a ID to the event data on nativescript-ui-calendar?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-telerik-ui

I can add a title, start and end date and a color to the event. But how do i add a ID to the event? When i tap on a event i get this data and i need to get a ID for the event so i can render the event on another page.

```
                              `==== object dump start ====
                             _ios: <TKCalendarEvent: 0x2823c1c20>
                             constructor: ()
                              ios: <TKCalendarEvent: 0x2823c1c20>
                             _setIsAllDay: ()
                             _getIsAllDay: ()
                             _setEndDate: ()
                             _getEndDate: ()
                             _setStartDate: ()
                             _getStartDate: ()
                             _setTitle: ()
                             _getTitle: ()
                             _setEventColor: ()
                            _getEventColor: ()
                            android: undefined
                            title: Test
                            startDate: Sun Dec 15 2019 15:43:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
                            endDate: Sun Dec 15 2019 15:43:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
                            isAllDay: false
                            eventColor: #C8BC1AD6
                            ==== object dump end ====
                            `
```

So that is the data i get, and i i need to be able to set a ID to the event and then get the ID when i get this data.

This is how i add the title, startdate, enddate and color:

```
`event = new calendarModule.CalendarEvent(taskArray[i].title, 
 startDate, endDate, false, colors[i * 10 % (colors.length - 1)]);`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `CalendarEvent` to add not just id but any attribute you like. Refer [documentation (Vue) here](https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/Calendar/populating-with-data#extending-the-calendarevent). It's written in TypeScript, you could use that as it is if you have a transpiller configured in your JS project Or translate it into JS (just remove typings, the run time already supports E6 syntax so you should be good).